# Django/httplib : transmitting request.raw_post_data with httplib

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, httplib

"AAaarg" ! Please HeLp !!!

Here is what I am trying to do ...

I have a Django site `site1`, which needs to access the API of another service `site2`. However, in order to do that, `site1` needs to use its own login credentials and stuff ...

Therefore I have written a small Django app, which duplicates urls of `site2`, but under the hood, uses `httplib2` to transmit the request almost identically (just authenticating and stuff). It works great in most of cases and it actually used to work great before for all cases (I don't really know what broke it, possibly the update Python 2.6 -> 2.7).

In order to transmit the POST/PUT data as is, I get it with :

```
post_data = request.raw_post_data
```

And then send it with httplib2 :

```
response, content = c.request(
    url,
    method,
    post_data,
    headers=headers,
)
```

Problem occurs when posting *multipart-data*, containing binary data such as an image. `httplib` (on top of which `httplib2` is built) when building the request string, tries to concatenate my `post_data` with some generated headers and stuff. And it seems like `request.raw_post_data` is `string` type while the generated stuff are `unicode`. Therefore, it tries to decode my `post_data` (which contains binary data) and freaks out !!!

c.f. `httplib` line 807 :

```
if isinstance(message_body, str):
    msg += message_body
```

Here is an extract of `message_body` (gotten with `request.raw_post_data`) :

```
'-----------------------------697585321193462802080194682\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"\r\n\r\nPUT\r\n-----------------------------697585321193462802080194682\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="jpegPhoto"; filename="crap.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xfe\x00\x13Created with GIMP\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x05\x03\x04\x04\x04\x03\x05\x04\x04\x04
```

Here is the content of `msg` :

```
u'POST /user/spiq/?username=spiq HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 40307\r\naccept-language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nhost: localhost:8000\r\naccept: application/json\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0\r\naccept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nconnection: keep-alive\r\nreferer: \r\ncookie: csrftoken=d9a3e014e5e366ee435b27ae7fc122af; sessionid=d5492a8d640e346b8ca56fa87e5cc439\r\ncontent-type: multipart/form-data\r\n\r\n'
```

So basically it is doomed ...

Any idea how should I proceed ? Can I turn my `post_data` to `unicode` without decoding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this: http://bugs.python.org/issue11898#msg138059 it looks like you might be okay if you ensure that the `url` argument is coerced into a `str`.

Comment: GREAT ! Thanks Tom nice catch !!! I should think more of looking into a Python bug ... that's the most convenient solution to one's problem :)